# Number of vptr created if derived class also has a virtual function which is not present in Base class

Tags: c++, vtable, vptr, run-time-polymorphism

```
class Base
{
    public:
    
    virtual void func1()
    {
        std::cout<<"Base func1"<<std::endl;
    }
   //virtual destructor

};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    
    virtual void func1()
    {
        std::cout<<"Derived Base func1"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    virtual void func2()
    {
        std::cout<<"Derived func2"<<std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Derived *d = new Derived;
    delete d;
}
```

I want to know if there will be two "vptr"s created for resolving virtual functions, one in the `Base` class which will be inherited in `Derived` class object for `func1` and other one in the `Derived` object for `func2`.

Comment: Have you checked sizes of both classes? https://wandbox.org/permlink/6znTdbKbkv5Yn6IB. It will not provide a generic answer, but might help. In linked implementation, there is only one vptr in `Derived`.

Comment: I have checked the size of the base class object and derived class object, it appears same on my system "8 bytes". But according to me, 2 vptr should be created in derived class object and one in base class object.

Comment: Why do you think so? If GCC creates just one vptr in `Derived` and we suppose it's Stdndard-compliant, then the Standard cannot require 2 vptrs.

Comment: BTW, terms "vptr", "vtable", and "virtual table" are not at all mentioned in the Standard. The virtual table mechanism is seemingly an implementation issue.

Comment: @Naresh "_should be created_" why?

Comment: @curiousguy To handle the virtual function of derived class.But i think derived class vptr overrides the base class vptr and that's the reason derived class object size is same as base class object. Am i correct?

Comment: @Naresh the layout of classes with virtual functions may be defined by the compiler writer, for the purpose of binary compatibility; it's outside the scope of the C++ std.

Answer (score 1):

On my GCC:

```
std::cout << sizeof(void*) << ' ' << sizeof(Derived) << '\n';
// Prints 8 8
```

So one vtable pointer is enough. I'd expect most other compilers to behave in the same way.

> derived class also has a virtual function which is not present in Base class

Virtual functions added in `Derived` are probably simply placed at the end of `Derived` vtable, after functions inherited from `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

vtable/vptr issues are platform specific implementation details, not generally covered by std. I can imagine implementations with no in-object vptr at all. But on most platforms I know, exactly one vptr entry serves all purposes for single inheritance and virtual inheritance. However there is no warranty for this to be portable behavior.

Comment: "_I can imagine_ How would such impl work? Would that leak memory, in general?

Comment: @curiousguy Why should it leak? One possible implementation is a static associative array that keeps  a record of <object,type> pairs(static map<void*,type_info*> rtti;).

Comment: It would leak if objects are not destroyed properly.

Comment: @curiousguy it is irrelevant to vt. The memory mgmt mechanism  is responsible for proper destruction and deallocation; whether or not the type is polymorphic is irrelevant.

Comment: How is the map cleaned up?

Comment: @curiousguy this is just a hypothetical implementation, but short answer is: whoewer(compiler generated code) populated the map, will clean it too. This is not the best approach, but it is one possible impl.

Comment: The issue is that anything not properly destructed will leave entries in the map unless there are other mechanisms to clean the map than the dtor.

Comment: @curiousguy I cannot see what con

Comment: @curiousguy No. What do you mean by improper destruction? UB is always UB. If a polymorphic object is not destructed, it still needs access to its virtual methods, otherwise it doesn't. I can not see what confuses you. There are reasons I have not seen such an implementation, and I know one. But it is not the none-existent problem you seek

Comment: To properly destruct an object you need to have its destructor called, implicitly or by an explicit dtor call.

Comment: @curiousguy how is it going make problems? The internal mechanisms of house keeping are invisible to the code. That is what every compiler(tool chain) is  supposed to handle. Programmer's code must stay out of it; this is supposed to be a black box to the code.

Comment: The problem is when user code fails to properly destroy an object it created, as I wrote. How would the "internal mechanisms of house keeping" that is "invisible to the code" be triggered if no destructor is called?

Comment: @curiousguy when no destructor is called, then the object is not destructed. What sort of code triggers such behavior? Improper exit returns memory back to a system and other sort of resource leak is almost inevitable.

Comment: You can simply remove a memory block or overwrite objects if you don't care that their dtor is run.

Comment: @curiousguy in either case you must trigger a UB in the 1st place. Otherwise, if the code is not ill-formed acordding to std conventions, no runtime error happens.

Comment: How is disposing of memory or reusing memory w/o calling dtor in any way undefined?

Comment: @curiousguy That is what you should answer.